# How to delete users who are logged in

Tags: tmux, ubuntu-20.04, openssh

can't access   root      pts/18 tmux(1804832).%13   -
can't access   root      pts/19 tmux(1804832).%15   -
can't access   root      pts/20 tmux(1804832).%16   -
can't access   root      pts/21 tmux(1804832).%17   -
can't access   root      pts/22 tmux(1804832).%18   -
can't access   root      pts/23 tmux(1804832).%19   -
can't access   root      pts/24 tmux(1804832).%20   -
can't access   root      pts/25 tmux(1804832).%22   -
can't access   root      pts/27 tmux(1804832).%23   -
can't access   root      pts/28 tmux(1804832).%24   -
can't access   root      pts/29 tmux(1804832).%25

We tried to remove them by killing the processes but they are still there.